# Magento2 : How to add Custom Block?

Tags: magento2.2, php-7

How to add custom block under payment method(admin order invoice)

[image]

Comment: Do you want to add static block?

Comment: no ... .........

Answer (score 7):

Create a module with name **Vendor_Module** by following below steps:

**Step 1:** Create **registration.php**

> app/code/Vendor/Module/registration.php

```
<?php

\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Vendor_Module',
    __DIR__
);
```

**Step 2:** Create **module.xml**

> app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Vendor_Module" setup_version="0.0.1">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Sales"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

**Step 3:** Create **sales_order_invoice_view.xml**

> app/code/Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/layout/sales_order_invoice_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="form" template="Vendor_Module::invoice/view/form.phtml"/>
        <referenceBlock name="form">
            <block class="Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Invoice" name="custom.invoice" as="custom_invoice" template="Vendor_Module::invoice/view/invoice.phtml"/>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

**Step 4:** Create **form.phtml**

> app/code/Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/templates/invoice/view/form.phtml

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

?>
<?php $_invoice = $block->getInvoice() ?>
<?php $_order = $_invoice->getOrder() ?>
<?= $block->getChildHtml('order_info') ?>

<section class="admin__page-section order-view-billing-shipping">
    <div class="admin__page-section-title">
        <span class="title"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Payment &amp; Shipping Method') ?></span>
    </div>
    <div class="admin__page-section-content">
        <div class="admin__page-section-item order-payment-method<?php if ($_order->getIsVirtual()): ?> order-payment-method-virtual<?php endif; ?> admin__fieldset-wrapper">
            <?php /*Billing Address */ ?>
            <div class="admin__page-section-item-title">
                <span class="title"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Payment Information') ?></span>
            </div>
            <div class="admin__page-section-item-content">
                <div class="order-payment-method-title"><?= $block->getChildHtml('order_payment') ?></div>
                <div class="order-payment-currency">
                    <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('The order was placed using %1.', $_order->getOrderCurrencyCode()) ?>
                </div>
                <div class="order-payment-additional"><?= $block->getChildHtml('order_payment_additional') ?></div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <?php if (!$_order->getIsVirtual()): ?>
            <div class="admin__page-section-item order-shipping-address">
                <?php /*Shipping Address */ ?>
                <div class="admin__page-section-item-title">
                    <span class="title"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Shipping Information') ?></span>
                </div>
                <div class="admin__page-section-item-content shipping-description-wrapper">
                    <div class="shipping-description-title">
                        <?= $block->escapeHtml($_order->getShippingDescription()) ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="shipping-description-content">
                        <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Total Shipping Charges') ?>:

                        <?php if ($this->helper('Magento\Tax\Helper\Data')->displayShippingPriceIncludingTax()): ?>
                            <?php $_excl = $block->displayShippingPriceInclTax($_order); ?>
                        <?php else: ?>
                            <?php $_excl = $block->displayPriceAttribute('shipping_amount', false, ' '); ?>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                        <?php $_incl = $block->displayShippingPriceInclTax($_order); ?>

                        <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_excl ?>
                        <?php if ($this->helper('Magento\Tax\Helper\Data')->displayShippingBothPrices() && $_incl != $_excl): ?>
                            (<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Incl. Tax') ?> <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_incl ?>)
                        <?php endif; ?>
                        <div><?= $block->getChildHtml('shipment_tracking') ?></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        <?php endif; ?>

    </div>
</section>

<section class="admin__page-section">
    <div class="admin__page-section-title">
        <span class="title"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Custom Title') ?></span>
    </div>
    <div id="invoice_custom_container" class="admin__page-section-content">
        <?= $block->getChildHtml('custom_invoice') ?>
    </div>
</section>

<section class="admin__page-section">
    <div class="admin__page-section-title">
        <span class="title"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Items Invoiced') ?></span>
    </div>

    <div id="invoice_item_container" class="admin__page-section-content">
        <?= $block->getChildHtml('invoice_items') ?>
    </div>
</section>

<section class="admin__page-section">
    <div class="admin__page-section-title">
        <span class="title"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Order Total') ?></span>
    </div>
    <div class="admin__page-section-content">
        <div class="admin__page-section-item order-comments-history">
            <div class="admin__page-section-item-title">
                <span class="title"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Invoice History') ?></span>
            </div>
            <div class="admin__page-section-item-content">
                <?= $block->getChildHtml('order_comments') ?>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="history_form" class="admin__page-section-item order-totals">
            <div class="admin__page-section-item-title">
                <span class="title"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Invoice Totals') ?></span>
            </div>
            <?= $block->getChildHtml('invoice_totals') ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

**Step 5:** Create **invoice.phtml**

> app/code/Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/templates/invoice/view/invoice.phtml

```
<?= $block->getText() ?>
```

**Step 6:** Create **Invoice.php**

> app/code/Vendor/Module/Block/Adminhtml/Invoice.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;

class Invoice extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    public function __construct(Template\Context $context, array $data = array())
    {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    public function getText(){
        return 'Custom text';
    }
}
```

**Step 7:** Create **adminhtml_order_shipment_view.xml**

> app/code/Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/layout/adminhtml_order_shipment_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="form" template="Vendor_Module::shipping/view/form.phtml">
            <block class="Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Shipping" name="custom.shipping" as="custom_shipping" template="Vendor_Module::shipping/view/shipping.phtml"/>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

**Step 8:** Create **form.phtml**

> app/code/Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/templates/shipping/view/form.phtml

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile
/**
 * @var \Magento\Shipping\Block\Adminhtml\View\Form $block
 */
$order = $block->getShipment()->getOrder();
?>
<?= $block->getChildHtml('order_info'); ?>
<section class="admin__page-section order-shipment-billing-shipping">
    <div class="admin__page-section-title">
        <span class="title"><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Payment &amp; Shipping Method')); ?></span>
    </div>
    <div class="admin__page-section-content">
        <div class="admin__page-section-item order-payment-method">
            <div class="admin__page-section-item-title">
                <span class="title"><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Payment Information')); ?></span>
            </div>
            <div class="admin__page-section-item-content">
                <div><?= $block->getChildHtml('order_payment') ?></div>
                <div class="order-payment-currency">
                    <?= $block->escapeHtml(__('The order was placed using %1.', $order->getOrderCurrencyCode())); ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="admin__page-section-item order-shipping-address">
            <div class="admin__page-section-item-title">
                <span class="title"><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Shipping and Tracking Information')); ?></span>
            </div>
            <div class="admin__page-section-item-content">
                <div class="shipping-description-wrapper">
                    <?php if ($block->getShipment()->getTracksCollection()->count()): ?>
                        <p>
                            <a href="#" id="linkId" onclick="popWin('<?= $block->escapeUrl($this->helper('Magento\Shipping\Helper\Data')->getTrackingPopupUrlBySalesModel($block->getShipment())); ?>','trackshipment','width=800,height=600,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes')"
                               title="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Track this shipment')); ?>">
                                <?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Track this shipment')); ?>
                            </a>
                        </p>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <div class="shipping-description-title">
                        <?= $block->escapeHtml($order->getShippingDescription()); ?>
                    </div>

                    <?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Total Shipping Charges')); ?>:

                    <?php if ($this->helper('Magento\Tax\Helper\Data')->displayShippingPriceIncludingTax()): ?>
                        <?php $excl = $block->displayShippingPriceInclTax($order); ?>
                    <?php else: ?>
                        <?php $excl = $block->displayPriceAttribute('shipping_amount', false, ' '); ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php $incl = $block->displayShippingPriceInclTax($order); ?>

                    <?= /* @noEscape */ $excl; ?>
                    <?php if ($this->helper('Magento\Tax\Helper\Data')->displayShippingBothPrices() && $incl != $excl): ?>
                        (<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Incl. Tax')); ?> <?= /* @noEscape */ $incl; ?>)
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </div>

                <p>
                    <?php if ($block->canCreateShippingLabel()): ?>
                        <?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getCreateLabelButton(); ?>
                    <?php endif ?>
                    <?php if ($block->getShipment()->getShippingLabel()): ?>
                        <?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getPrintLabelButton(); ?>
                    <?php endif ?>
                    <?php if ($block->getShipment()->getPackages()): ?>
                        <?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getShowPackagesButton(); ?>
                    <?php endif ?>
                </p>
                <?= $block->getChildHtml('shipment_tracking'); ?>

                <?= $block->getChildHtml('shipment_packaging'); ?>
                <script>
                    require([
                        'jquery',
                        'prototype'
                    ], function (jQuery) {
                        var setCallbacks = function () {
                            window.packaging.setConfirmPackagingCallback(function () {
                                window.packaging.sendCreateLabelRequest();
                            });
                            window.packaging.setLabelCreatedCallback(function () {
                                setLocation("<?php echo $block->escapeUrl($block->getUrl(
                                    'adminhtml/order_shipment/view',
                                    ['shipment_id' => $block->getShipment()->getId()])
                                ); ?>");
                            });
                        };

                        if (jQuery(document).data('packagingInited')) {
                            setCallbacks();
                        } else {
                            jQuery(document).on('packaging:inited', setCallbacks);
                        }
                    });
                </script>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
<section class="admin__page-section">
    <div class="admin__page-section-title">
        <span class="title"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Custom Title') ?></span>
    </div>
    <div id="invoice_custom_container" class="admin__page-section-content">
        <?= $block->getChildHtml('custom_shipping') ?>
    </div>
</section>
<section class="admin__page-section">
    <div class="admin__page-section-title">
        <span class="title"><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Items Shipped')); ?></span>
    </div>
    <?= $block->getChildHtml('shipment_items'); ?>
</section>

<section class="admin__page-section">
    <div class="admin__page-section-title">
        <span class="title"><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Order Total')); ?></span>
    </div>
    <div class="admin__page-section-content">
        <?= $block->getChildHtml('shipment_packed'); ?>

        <div class="admin__page-section-item order-comments-history">
            <div class="admin__page-section-item-title">
                <span class="title"><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Shipment History')); ?></span>
            </div>
            <div class="admin__page-section-item-content"><?= $block->getChildHtml('order_comments'); ?></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

**Step 9:** Create **shipping.phtml**

> app/code/Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/templates/shipping/view/shipping.phtml

```
<?= $block->getText() ?>
```

**Step 10:** Create **Shipping.php**

> app/code/Vendor/Module/Block/Adminhtml/Shipping.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;

class Shipping extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    public function __construct(Template\Context $context, array $data = array())
    {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    public function getText(){
        return 'Custom text';
    }
}
```

**Step 11:** Create **sales_order_creditmemo_view.xml**

> app/code/Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/layout/sales_order_creditmemo_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="form" template="Vendor_Module::creditmemo/view/form.phtml">
            <block class="Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Creditmemo" name="custom.creditmemo" as="custom_creditmemo" template="Vendor_Module::creditmemo/view/creditmemo.phtml"/>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

**Step 12:** Create **form.phtml**

> app/code/Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/templates/creditmemo/view/form.phtml

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

?>
<?php  $_order = $block->getCreditmemo()->getOrder() ?>
<?= $block->getChildHtml('order_info') ?>
<section class="admin__page-section">
    <div class="admin__page-section-title">
        <span class="title"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Payment &amp; Shipping Method') ?></span>
    </div>
    <div class="admin__page-section-content">

        <?php if (!$_order->getIsVirtual()): ?>
        <div class="admin__page-section-item order-payment-method">
        <?php else: ?>
        <div class="admin__page-section-item order-payment-method order-payment-method-virtual">
        <?php endif; ?>
            <?php /* Billing Address */?>
            <div class="admin__page-section-item-title">
                <span class="title"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Payment Information') ?></span>
            </div>
            <div class="admin__page-section-item-content">
                <div class="order-payment-method-title"><?= $block->getChildHtml('order_payment') ?></div>
                <div class="order-payment-currency"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('The order was placed using %1.', $_order->getOrderCurrencyCode()) ?></div>
                <div class="order-payment-additional"><?= $block->getChildHtml('order_payment_additional') ?></div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <?php if (!$_order->getIsVirtual()): ?>
        <div class="admin__page-section-item order-shipping-address">
            <?php /* Shipping Address */ ?>
            <div class="admin__page-section-item-title">
                <span class="title"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Shipping Information') ?></span>
            </div>
            <div class="shipping-description-wrapper admin__page-section-item-content">
                <div class="shipping-description-title"><?= $block->escapeHtml($_order->getShippingDescription()) ?></div>
                <div class="shipping-description-content">
                    <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Total Shipping Charges') ?>:

                    <?php if ($this->helper('Magento\Tax\Helper\Data')->displayShippingPriceIncludingTax()): ?>
                        <?php $_excl = $block->displayShippingPriceInclTax($_order); ?>
                    <?php else: ?>
                        <?php $_excl = $block->displayPriceAttribute('shipping_amount', false, ' '); ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php $_incl = $block->displayShippingPriceInclTax($_order); ?>

                    <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_excl ?>
                    <?php if ($this->helper('Magento\Tax\Helper\Data')->displayShippingBothPrices() && $_incl != $_excl): ?>
                        (<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Incl. Tax') ?> <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_incl ?>)
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
</section>
<section class="admin__page-section">
    <div class="admin__page-section-title">
        <span class="title"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Custom Title') ?></span>
    </div>
    <div id="invoice_custom_container" class="admin__page-section-content">
        <?= $block->getChildHtml('custom_creditmemo') ?>
    </div>
</section>
<?php $_items = $block->getCreditmemo()->getAllItems() ?>

<?php if (count($_items)): ?>
<div id="creditmemo_items_container">
    <?= $block->getChildHtml('creditmemo_items') ?>
</div>
<?php else: ?>
<section class="admin__page-section">
    <div class="admin__page-section-title">
        <span class="title"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Items Refunded') ?></span>
    </div>
    <div class="no-items admin__page-section-content"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('No Items') ?></div>
</section>
<?php endif; ?>

<section class="admin__page-section">
    <div class="admin__page-section-title">
        <span class="title"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Memo Total') ?></span>
    </div>
    <div class="admin__page-section-content">
        <div class="admin__page-section-item order-comments-history">
            <div class="admin__page-section-item-title">
                <span class="title"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Credit Memo History') ?></span>
            </div>
            <div class="admin__page-section-item-content"><?= $block->getChildHtml('order_comments') ?></div>
        </div>
        <div class="admin__page-section-item order-totals" id="history_form">
            <div class="admin__page-section-item-title">
                <span class="title"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Credit Memo Totals') ?></span>
            </div>
            <div class="admin__page-section-content"><?= $block->getChildHtml('creditmemo_totals') ?></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

**Step 13:** Create **creditmemo.phtml**

> app/code/Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/templates/creditmemo/view/creditmemo.phtml

```
<?= $block->getText() ?>
```

**Step 14:** Create **Creditmemo.php**

> app/code/Vendor/Module/Block/Adminhtml/Creditmemo.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;

class Creditmemo extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    public function __construct(Template\Context $context, array $data = array())
    {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    public function getText(){
        return 'Custom text';
    }
}
```

**Step 15:** Create **sales_order_view.xml**

> app/code/Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/layout/sales_order_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="order_tab_info" template="Vendor_Module::order/view/tab/info.phtml">
            <block class="Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Order" name="custom.order" as="custom_order" template="Vendor_Module::order/view/order.phtml"/>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

**Step 16:** Create **info.phtml**

> app/code/Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/templates/order/view/tab/info.phtml

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

?>
<?php /** @var $block \Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Tab\Info */ ?>
<?php $_order = $block->getOrder() ?>

<div id="order-messages">
    <?= $block->getChildHtml('order_messages') ?>
</div>

<?= $block->getChildHtml('order_info') ?>
<input type="hidden" name="order_id" value="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_order->getId() ?>"/>

<section class="admin__page-section order-view-billing-shipping">
    <div class="admin__page-section-title">
        <span class="title"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Payment &amp; Shipping Method') ?></span>
    </div>
    <div class="admin__page-section-content">
        <div class="admin__page-section-item order-payment-method<?php if ($_order->getIsVirtual()): ?> order-payment-method-virtual<?php endif; ?>">
            <?php /* Payment Method */ ?>
            <div class="admin__page-section-item-title">
                <span class="title"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Payment Information') ?></span>
            </div>
            <div class="admin__page-section-item-content">
                <div class="order-payment-method-title"><?= $block->getPaymentHtml() ?></div>
                <div class="order-payment-currency"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('The order was placed using %1.', $_order->getOrderCurrencyCode()) ?></div>
                <div class="order-payment-additional">
                    <?= $block->getChildHtml('order_payment_additional') ?>
                    <?= $block->getChildHtml('payment_additional_info') ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?= $block->getChildHtml('order_shipping_view') ?>
    </div>
</section>
<section class="admin__page-section">
    <div class="admin__page-section-title">
        <span class="title"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Custom Title') ?></span>
    </div>
    <div id="invoice_custom_container" class="admin__page-section-content">
        <?= $block->getChildHtml('custom_order') ?>
    </div>
</section>
<?= $block->getChildHtml('order_additional_info') ?>

<?= $block->getGiftOptionsHtml() ?>

<section class="admin__page-section">
    <div class="admin__page-section-title">
        <span class="title"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Items Ordered') ?></span>
    </div>
    <?= $block->getItemsHtml() ?>
</section>

<section class="admin__page-section">
    <div class="admin__page-section-title">
        <span class="title"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Order Total') ?></span>
    </div>
    <div class="admin__page-section-content">
        <div class="admin__page-section-item order-comments-history">
            <div class="admin__page-section-item-title">
                <span class="title"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Notes for this Order') ?></span>
            </div>
            <?= $block->getChildHtml('order_history') ?>
        </div>

        <div class="admin__page-section-item order-totals">
            <div class="admin__page-section-item-title">
                <span class="title"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Order Totals') ?></span>
            </div>
            <?= $block->getChildHtml('order_totals') ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>

<?= $block->getChildHtml('popup_window') ?>

<script>
require([
    "prototype",
    "Magento_Sales/order/giftoptions_tooltip"
], function(){

//<![CDATA[
    /**
     * Retrieve gift options tooltip content
     */
    function getGiftOptionsTooltipContent(itemId) {
        var contentLines = [];
        var headerLine = null;
        var contentLine = null;

        $$('#gift_options_data_' + itemId + ' .gift-options-tooltip-content').each(function (element) {
            if (element.down(0)) {
                headerLine = element.down(0).innerHTML;
                contentLine = element.down(0).next().innerHTML;
                if (contentLine.length > 30) {
                    contentLine = contentLine.slice(0,30) + '...';
                }
                contentLines.push(headerLine + ' ' + contentLine);
            }
        });
        return contentLines.join('<br/>');
    }
    giftOptionsTooltip.setTooltipContentLoaderFunction(getGiftOptionsTooltipContent);
    window.getGiftOptionsTooltipContent = getGiftOptionsTooltipContent;
//]]>

});
</script>
```

**Step 17:** Create **order.phtml**

> app/code/Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/templates/order/view/order.phtml

```
<?= $block->getText() ?>
```

**Step 18:** Create **Order.php**

> app/code/Vendor/Module/Block/Adminhtml/Order.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;

class Order extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    public function __construct(Template\Context $context, array $data = array())
    {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    public function getText(){
        return 'Custom text';
    }
}
```

Thats it!. Now run setup upgrade and other required commands and check.

Comment: I want to add some text under payment method in following layout files like sales_order_view, sales_order_invoice,sales_order_invoice_view, sales_order_creditmemo

Comment: Does the above is working for invoice view? Can you add a screenshot how you want?

Comment: yes  working.......

Comment: So you want the same thing for others as well. Right?

Comment: yes ...like adding fee in total section of all layout files

Comment: Adding fee is different thing which is totally different from the question you have asked.

Comment: Ok ....... i just saying like display custom text in all layout

Comment: Ok I ll update my answer so that it will also show the same thing for mentioned pages.

Comment: How do you want to show it in sales_order_invoice and sales_order_creditmemo? You can only show custom text in all view pages. Please confirm.

Comment: Yes i want to show it...

Comment: I have updated the answer. Please check.

Comment: In creditmemo template?

Comment: I ll update it tomorrow. Somehow it's not updated.

Comment: @ManoM Can you please check the updated answer?

Comment: Is it working for you? You have not accepted yet?

Comment: @SukumarGorai i want to include a google business review into my phtml file, How to create a block, and include my google business review api into that and call in my phtml file.https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/336365/57334

Answer (score 1):

You can use **Magento 2 plugin system** to show custom HTML block or text under payment information in the backend. It shows on Orders, Invoices, Shipments and Credit Memos just by changing one method.

Here, I just created a plugin class `MilanDev\PaymentText\Plugin\Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock` and append custom text in the `afterGetChildHtml` method while `order_payment` block is loaded. Please follow the codes below:

> app/code/MilanDev/PaymentText/etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="MilanDev_PaymentText" setup_version="1.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Framework"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

> app/code/MilanDev/PaymentText/etc/adminhtml/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock">
        <plugin disabled="false" name="MilanDev_PaymentText_Plugin_Magento_Framework_View_Element_AbstractBlock" sortOrder="10" type="MilanDev\PaymentText\Plugin\Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

> app/code/MilanDev/PaymentText/registration.php

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'MilanDev_PaymentText',
    __DIR__
);
```

> app/code/MilanDev/PaymentText/Plugin/Magento/Framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php

```
<?php
namespace MilanDev\PaymentText\Plugin\Magento\Framework\View\Element;

    class AbstractBlock
    {

        public function afterGetChildHtml(
            \Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock $subject,
            $result
        ) {

            // you can pull the custom text dynamically here
            $customText = '<p style="color:red;">Custom text for payment information!</p>'; 

            if ($subject->getNameInLayout() == 'order_payment') {
                return $result . $customText;
            } 

            return $result;
        }
    }
```

Comment: How to add template for this block

Comment: Hi Milan Chandro, i want to include a google business review into my phtml file, How to create a block, and include my google business review api into that and call in my phtml file.https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/336365/57334